# 4 apps get installed after every reboot, how to remove them

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, micromax-a110

I am using Micromax canvas turbo with Android 4.0 ICS.

I once tried to root my phone, but didn't find any good use so reverted it.

Now I have 4 apps:

1. Hola Luancher
2. One touch white
3. One touch Black
4. Lazy swipe

And I also have some internal app getting installed like:

1. TimeService
2. MusicProvider
3. backUpProvider

They all get installed and enabled after every reboot. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Factory Reset. Back up your data and perform a factory reset, and if that doesn't work, then you will need to root your phone to get rid of them. :|

Comment: i tried to root my phone , can you give any trusted rooting tutorial link ??

Comment: Another solution is to go to their app settings and disable them. It won't remove them from memory, but it will act like they are not there

Comment: I have tried disabling them , but they also get enabled after every reboot